# Какими способами можно реализовать общие переменные помимо static?

Tags: c#, unity3d, static

Есть `bool` и `list<T>`, которые динамически меняются в нескольких объектах, при этом являются общими.
Использовать `GetComponent` затратно. Помимо static есть другой способ, а если нет, то как лучше реализовать?

Comment: Выделить отдельный класс и передать его инстанс как зависимость всем объектам, которым он нужен